# DataTables, Ajax Pipelining

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using DataTables with [pipelining](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/pipeline.html). I works great except when I tried to enter an extra column to hold "edit" links. See [this](http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ajax-inlinebuttons.html) table.

Here is a snippet of server_processing.php showing the columns:

```
   /* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
    * Use a space where you want to insert a 
    * non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
    */
    $aColumns = array( 'user','email', );
```

And here is the clientside:

```
    $(document).ready( function (){
       $('#example').dataTable({
          "bProcessing": true,
          "bServerSide": true,
          "sAjaxSource": "scripts/server_processing.php",
          "fnServerData": fnDataTablesPipeline,
          aoColumns: [null, null, {"bSortable": false}]
    }).makeEditable({
       sUpdateURL: "UpdateData.php",
       sAddURL: "AddData.php",
       sAddHttpMethod: "POST",
       sDeleteURL: "DeleteData.php",
       sDeleteHttpMethod: "POST",
       aoColumns: [ { } , { } , null ]
    });
  });
```

So, why isn't this working?

Comment: My experience with DataTables does not include using pipelining, but when adding a "virtual column" - for say, an edit column, checkbox, calculcated row, generally you will need to add a placeholder for it in your `aoColumns` array. So I would change `aoColumns: [null, null, {"bSortable": false}]`aoColumns: [null, null, {"bSortable": false}] to `aoColumns: [null, null, null, {"bSortable": false}]`

Comment: also, the guy who wrote dataTables (Alan Jardine I think?) is great at helping out if you have any questions. He is very heplful and obviously noone knows the plug in better than the creator himself!

Answer (score 3):

Just done this exact same thing myself.  I like to configure all my columns using `aoColumnDefs`, as you can add multiple configuration options for columns in one go.

```
// Disable sorting on the 3rd column
'aoColumnDefs': [{'aTargets': [2], 'bSortable': false}]
```

Note that `aTargets` is an array of column indexes you want to apply those settings to.  So if you were to add more link columns (e.g. a Delete link), you can turn off sorting on those without rewriting the column definition every time.

```
// Disable sorting on the 3rd and 4th column
'aoColumnDefs': [{'aTargets': [2,3], 'bSortable': false}]
```

And, as I was saying, you can add further configuration options for columns in this same array:

```
// Disable sorting on the 3rd and 4th column and sort 1st column by string
'aoColumnDefs': [
    {'aTargets': [2,3], 'bSortable': false}
    {'aTargets': [0], 'sType': 'string'}
]
```